# Build a python package: how to call non code files in a package's main script

Tags: python, package

I have a project that I manage to package, distribute, install and import. My package directory looks something like:

```
/
pkg/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   data/
       data_1
       data_2.sav
       data_3.bin
```

The problem is that `main.py` is dependent on non code files inside the `data` directory, and when I call `main.py`, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/data_1'
```

Additional:

- all data files are being packaged correctly
- in `main.py`, the data files are called as:

  `data =  pickle.load(open('data/data_1', "rb"))`

The main script is not finding the data files for some reason. What can possibly be wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Since the file path you use is not absolute, you need to find out what the working directory.  Add this somewhere in main.py: `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Thanks @FiddleStix - the path I was using was incomplete. Yours and ttekampe suggestions worked well together for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the path is interpreted relatively from where you are executing main.py
Maybe this works:

```
import os

this_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
data =  pickle.load(open(
     os.path.join(this_path, 'data/data_1'),
    "rb"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

With python 3.4+, you can use the **Pathlib** module as below:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = (Path(__file__).parent / "../data/data_1").resolve()
```